# How can I make both side of a rectangle equal in c?

Tags: c, for-loop, printf, scanf, space

The user inputs length and height and the program should draw a rectangle with those characteristics and empty in the middle. The problem is that the program prints out a side longer than the other. (Note: the "x" is just a symbol that I used for drawing the rectangle, not a variable.)

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float lenght,height,i,j;
    printf("insert lenght:\n");
    scanf("%f",&lenght);
    printf("insert height:\n");
    scanf("%f",& height);
    for (i=0; i<lenght; i++) //upper lenght
    {
        printf("x");
    }
    for (i=0; i<height; i++) //height
    {
        printf("x\n");
        for (j=0; j<lenght; j++) //space
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("x\n");
    }
    for (j=0; j<=lenght; j++) //lower lenght
    {
        printf("x");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output, for example, for input `10 5`?

Comment: Think about the loop controls: the horizontal spaces should be 2 less than the width, and similarly for the height. So the height loop should be `for (i=2; i<height; i++)` and the spacing loop should be `for (j=2; j<lenght; j++)`

Comment: Using `float` as loop counter looks unusual.

Comment: ...you should also remove the newline from the left-hand border output `printf("x\n");` and add one after the top row.

Comment: @MikeCAT the expected output is a rectangle with width=10 and height=5

Answer (score 1):

The perfect and reliable way to do it (notice comments):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int rows, columns;
    
    printf("Input total rows and columns: ");

    if (scanf("%d%d", &rows, &columns) != 2) {
        // If the 'rows' and/or 'columns' are entered incorrectly
        printf("Please input the values correctly!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Iteration till 'rows'
    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        // Iteration till 'columns'
        for (int j = 1; j <= columns; j++)
            // Meanwhile, if 'i' is the first iteration or last iteration relative to 'rows'
            // it will print an asterisk and similarly with 'j', otherwise, a space
            if (i == 1 || i == rows || j == 1 || j == columns)
                printf("*");
            else
                printf(" ");

        // Will go to the next line on each iteration
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**A sample test case:**

```
Input total rows and columns: 5 10
**********
*        *
*        *
*        *
**********

Input total rows and columns: 10 10
**********
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
*        *
**********
```

Comment: well, it's not what i asked,the program asks the user to input height and width,it's a similar but DIFFERENT PROGRAM, however thanks for your answer.

Comment: @NomeAcaso then what did you intend to make? Was not a hollow rectangle?

Comment: I guess you're right,I mean I'm a bit confused because you used a more complicated code , I didn't actually get what you did(for example the if statement you used)I'm not really advanced I just started learning how to program 2 weeks ago.

Comment: @NomeAcaso your height and width means rows and columns in correct words and yes, two weeks are enough to learn the basics. :)

Comment: alright but calm down man I didn't mean to attack you or anything